# Listing technologies/languages in LinkedIn Project History a Security Issue?

Tags: exposure

In my LinkedIn Profile, when I list my past projects as a Software Developer, I think it to be beneficial to list the technologies/languages used.

My question is, does this impose a security risk/threat in any way?

Answer (score 2):

No, not really. In most cases it's not difficult to work out the language/tech used for a particular site or application anyway. Doing your best to hide it would just be security through obscurity. Maybe people will find it a little easier to ID the language/tech used in your projects if you tell them, but they'd find it anyway.